# Alter view sql date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, alter

I have an assignment to change the existing date format in an existing T-SQL view statement. Where the date format is set to `YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00.000` the task is to change is to ALTER VIEW to `MM-DD-YY` formatting. I'm lost on this one.

```
USE Ch8_simpleco

ALTER VIEW 
AS invoice
    SELECT INV_DATE
    SET INV_DATE (MMDDYY)
    FROM dbo.v_cust_invoices;
```

Comment: Read up on CAST and CONVERT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
ALTER VIEW invoice
AS
    SELECT COVERT(char(8), INV_DATE, 10) -- will get you dd-MM-yy (no century!)
    FROM dbo.v_cust_invoices
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FORMAT()  like this:

```
ALTER VIEW invoice
AS
    SELECT FROMAT(INV_DATE,'MM-dd-yy') as INV_DATE
    FROM dbo.v_cust_invoices
```